# Tool-chain version checks in Jupyter notebooks or Python

Tags: python, version, toolchain

Is there a quick or easy way to use the import list in a python script to check all the versions of all the libraries and their dependencies all at once?

something like:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)
```

But with a little less effort to display *ALL* of the libraries used like matplotlib, scipy, pandas, opencv, etc.

Comment: you could loop on the modules, import them & get version with something like `__import__("sys").version`

Comment: so... no one-liners? but this is pretty handy too.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: create a list with the versions of all imported libraries to include with the documentation of the project. was hoping there is some sort of one-line code that could perform this.

Comment: what if the imported libraries import some other libraries?

Comment: that is why i would like to know if there is a simple way to list all the dependencies also.